# Kuberneter cluster diagram for micro service deployment

Tags: kubernetes

AM looking for a kubernetes cluster diagram with all infrastruture requirements like Databse,App servers, Micro service ,Cloud network . Am only finding architecture but not this.Any reference is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some reference diagrams

### Diagram 1

[image]

### Diagram 2

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing .Both the diagrams doesnt fit for my requirement

Comment: those are just for reference. dont use them as is. you need to make edits as per your deployment architecture